# Google data Studio- Bar Chart Click Event

Tags: looker-studio

I have created a created a bar chart in google data Studio. I have a requirement that on click of a bar chart a table should display with each records individually. 
In attached bar chart I have Counts against each booking category. Suppose If I click on GRP REL bar it should display all the bookings at row level in sepearate table

[image: In attached bar chart I have Counts against each booking category. Suppose If I click on GRP REL bar it should display all the bookings at row level in sepearate table(162 records)]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

You can't create click actions like this in Data Studio.